# How to build and optimize MySQL DB for multi-dimensional search?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, search

I want to create a table with columns like: A1, A2, A3, L1, L2, L3, L4

The main job for this database is:

User provides some float number: a, b, c, d, then find the best one that have min Euclidean distance, that is the min of (a-L1)^2+(b-L2)^2+(c-L3)^2+(d-L4)^2

Also, some time user may provides some range information for A1, A2, A3,

e.g., A1 > 0.15, 2 < A2 < 3.5, A3 <= 1.2

and then based on these constraints, do the search for L1-L4.

I have read some topics related to this and done a test to insert all data into MySQL using MyISAM engine, and use command like:

```
select * from table1
order by (x-L1)*(x-L1)+ (y-L2)*(y-L2)+ (z-L3)*(z-L3) 
limit 1
```

But I want to improve the speed as fast as possible, I noticed that there are some optimization part. But still not clear how to do them, and which of them suitable for my case:

1. there are column index, but based on my problem, how to build index?
2. also there are "SPATIAL indexes", can I benefit from this? How to use this?
3. which search command should I use? stick on the "order" one that I'm using?
4. Anything else for improving the speed?
5. All the work are done in C/C++, I'm now using MySQL C API, and using mysql_query() function, is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

your result will be based on a specific formula.

As you are using Mysql 5 (i assume)  can you try to create a `procedure` and after compiling

when ever you want you can call and performance will be better than the normal select query i guess.

you can pass the input parameters for that **stored procedure** as the range.

you can use **indexes** if you think the result set is based on any **key**.

but i dont really understand you have any key!!

The Mysql and C combination am hearing it for first time. i dont know how you will be seeing the result.(my less knowledge) :-(

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still at the stage of experimenting with MySQL, you might also want to look into using Postgres.

It has a bunch of [geometry types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-geometric.html), for one.

And Postgres 9.1 in particular (in beta) implements out of the box [k-nearest searches](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/pgcon-2010-1.pdf) using the [gist index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html) (see E.1.3.5.5. Indexes). If the latter implementation doesn't fit your exact requirements, you'll also find it interesting that gist indexes are [extensible](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/gist-implementation.html).

Comment: I found that MySQL also has this kind of type for GIS

Comment: It can, but at the price of using MyISAM, which sacrifices ACID and is rather prone (in my experience anyway) to data corruption. Also, Postgres comes with CTEs and WITH queries, both of which tend to be very useful.